# Facing some problem but can't solved this

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

When i using this below without where condition query i get the values

Model:

```
 public function get_teacher_number() {
        $this->db->select('staff.*');
        $this->db->from('staff');
        $this->db->join('staff_roles','staff.id=staff_roles.staff_id','inner');         
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

Output:

```
2323232,262626,32323,,26262623265265,
```

When i using this below with where condition query i can't get all the values it show me just one value but when i tried this sql in my mysql server its show me 2 values and here i get only one value.

Model:

```
public function get_teacher_number() {
    $this->db->select('staff.*');
    $this->db->from('staff');
    $this->db->join('staff_roles','staff.id=staff_roles.staff_id','inner'); 
    $this->db->where('staff_roles.role_id',2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Output:

```
262626,,
```

one value is missing..

Here i give you controller code:

```
$all_teacher = $this->teacher_model->get_teacher_number();
 $x = '';
 foreach ($all_teacher as $val) {
    $smsid= $val["id"];
    $number = $val["contact_no"];
    $x = $x.$number.","; //number separated by comma
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($x);
  exit();
```

Comment: please check in database that In `staff` table two record which having `staff_roles.role_id = 2`

Comment: yes there is two records in staff tables

Comment: Okay now check both record staff.id and staff_roles.staff_id are same ??

Comment: ok thanks bro i solved it